# Modern filesystems use ordered tree or unordered tree?

Tags: filesystems

I want to know whether modern filesystems (like ext4 btrfs xfs zfs ntfs apfs) use ordered tree or unordered tree? This question comes from a exam problem which asks the worst case of access to the hard drive when finding `\A\D\G\H\K` (if use ordered tree, accessing `\D` and `\H` will be faster as it is the first child node)

[image]

Comment: ordered ? Do you mean how each directory entry is indexed in the array ? (which might be totally unrelated to the speed of the algo for finding the entry associated to some given index.)